# Punctuation space after number in footnotes

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, character-styles, footnotes

I'm working on a journal in which there is a lot of footnotes. (17 articles, aprox 30 pages each with at least 30 footnotes).
I use superscript nested style to make the number of every footnote in footer superscript, but I wonder if there is a way in which I can add a space after footnote number and before text (so I don't have to do it manually). Punctuation space would suit me well, but I'm not very good with grep styles so I don't know how exactly to formulate it so it works.

Comment: Are you talking about the footnote number in the body text, or in the footnote at the bottom of the page?

Comment: *If* it is InDesign you are talking about – some clarification here could be useful – then adjust what goes after the number in the Document Footnote Options.

Comment: I do understand how radical this sounds and still, if you really think you can justify any footnote, please post it.

Endnotes are bad enough but why would anyone ever want to use footnotes, other than for copying someone else?

Seriously, either incorporate it into the main text, or make it an endnote. How or why is that difficult?

That aside, how you handle spaces and/or numbers is purely a matter of style, which is to say, choice.

If your institution has a style, follow that. Otherwise, look further out, choose a style and follow that.

Comment: We use Oxford style referencing in footnotes at my faculty, that's why I use footnotes. And btw, I really (really) hate endnotes.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Funny, I would say the exact opposite. There are plenty of good uses for notes (much academic writing would be horrible without them), but in nearly all cases, endnotes are an abomination that needs to die, or rather, be turned into footnotes.

Comment: Really, Janus? Please list even three examples of any writing, academic or otherwise, that in any way benefit from footnotes…

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about InDesign. Grep styles do not currently (as of CC2018) support editing. They can only identify and apply styles to the matched result.

EDIT:
Thanks for the update.
Here is a way to add space after the footnotes in InDesign:

1. Go to Text>Footnote Options
2. Check "Show Prefix/Suffix in: Select "Footnote Reference," "Footnote
   Text," or "Both Reference and Text"as needed. (experiment to find
   the right one for your needs.)
3. Enter space characters in the Prefix and Suffix fields.
4. Click OK.

That should do it.

Comment: Yes, it's Indesign and it concerns footnote number in footer